# 530 Permission Denied accessing FTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, windows-server-2019

I'm using a portable version of [Xlight FTP Server](https://www.xlightftpd.com/) Personal for Windows.  I have created a "Virtual server" running on port 21 with no SSL enabled. I have added Firewall rules. I have created a user with a very simple username and password.  I have also tried anonymous login.  I have set the user path to c:\ and given `RWCLA--S` permissions.  I have tried turning PASV mode off on the client.

When I attempt to login from another machine (I have used WinSCP and FTP command) I just get a "530 permission denied" error.

What else am I missing?

Here is the log from the server:

```
07/24/2020 15:43:37 (not login x.x.40.164<--x.x.42.64:21) "220 Xlight FTP Server 3.9 ready..."
07/24/2020 15:43:37 (not login x.x.40.164-->x.x.42.64:21) "OPTS UTF8 ON"
07/24/2020 15:43:37 (not login x.x.40.164<--x.x.42.64:21) "530 Not login, please login first"
07/24/2020 15:43:40 (not login x.x.40.164-->x.x.42.64:21) "USER ftpusr"
07/24/2020 15:43:40 (not login x.x.40.164<--x.x.42.64:21) "331 Password required for ftpusr"
07/24/2020 15:43:41 (not login x.x.40.164-->x.x.42.64:21) "PASS *****"
07/24/2020 15:43:41 (not login x.x.40.164<--x.x.42.64:21) "530 Permission denied"
```

Comment: Hi, The Windows security permission on the folder is ok ? I ask as if ftpusr is a username local the ftp service, not AD, often the ftp software will use a guest's account to access the folder path. If it's an AD user, make sure the account have access to the folder

Comment: That was the issue. I added `everyone` to the Windows permissions for the folder and now it works. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows security permission on the folder is ok ?

I ask as if ftpusr is a username local the ftp service, not AD, often the ftp software will use a guest's account to access the folder path.

If it's an AD user, make sure the account have access to the folder.

Comment: I added `everyone` with read/write to the Windows permissions for the folder (c:\FTProot\ in this case) and now I can connect.